# Making PHP forms questions auto answered by link

Tags: php

I'm using a PHP contact form template. I want it to automatically put in answers by using a link.

What I mean by this is that when you click this link 
(http://minecraft-accounts.org/contact/index.php?account=Test)

It automatically fills in the answer of the account section. But when you type in just the normal link (http://minecraft-accounts.org/contact/index.php)

All the boxes are blank. How would I make it so a template form can do this?

Here is the code of the form from the internet? [code](http://pastebin.com/ZTRLFgW8)

Answer (score 2):

in this case if you want pass data from url you can use this inside html elements:

`<input type="text" value="<?PHP  echo $_GET['account']  ?>"/>`
of course you can use smarty variables too!!!

Answer (score 2):

Its very simple. in URL which you have provided set a query string named account. you can also do this like this...

for example your URL: www.abc.com?account=123
then code will like this

```
  <input type="text" value="<?php echo $_GET["account"] ?>">
```

Answer (score 1):

I would check, if the variable `isset();`
So your coude should look something like that

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>My Webpage</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php
            $account = "";
            $mail = "";
            $message = "";

            if(isset($_GET['account'])) {
                $account = $_GET['account'];
            }

            if(isset($_GET['mail'])) {
                $mail = $_GET['mail'];
            }

            if(isset($_GET['message'])) {
                $message = $_GET['message'];
            }
        ?>
        <table border="0">
            <tr>
                <td>Account-Name:</td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" value="<?php echo $account; ?>">
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Mail:</td>
                <td>
                    <input type="mail" value="<?php echo $mail; ?>">
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Message:</td>
                <td>
                    <textarea>
                        <?php echo $message; ?>
                    </textarea>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

So the URL can be: http://www.example.com/register.php?account=DonaldDuck&message=Hello%20my%20name%20is%20Donald

And the inputs `Account` and `Message` get filled.

It can also be: http://www.example.com/register.php?account=DonaldDuck and it still works with no error.

For more information see: http://php.net/manual/de/function.isset.php